# Old package version number after update with NPM

Tags: npm

I'v updated bower 1.2.8 to latest version with this command.

```
sudo npm update bower -g
```

After update, I got this version number with this command.

```
bower -v
1.2.8
```

Why?

When I check bower package with this command, the latest version is installed.

```
npm list bower -g
/Users/uracle/npm/lib
└── bower@1.3.1
```

Other package has same problem.(phonegap, etc...)

Comment: what does `$ where bower` show?

Comment: where? -bash: where: command not found

Comment: Try which bower. That will at least show you where bower is installed and that will give some insight